# How to concat a const char * to a NSString *

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

Trying to append `const char *str` to a `NSSting *`:

In .h

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString    *consoleText;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *consoleText;

@end
```

In .mm

```
@synthesize consoleText;
```

The following is OK:

```
const char *str = "abc";

self.consoleText = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", self.consoleText, [NSString stringWithUTF8String:str]];
```

but the following failed:

```
self.consoleText = [self.consoleText stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:str]];
```

Why `stringByAppendingString` fails but `stringWithFormat` works? Thanks!

Comment: What to you mean by "failed" ? crash ? bad string ?

Comment: @sloonz the string does not concat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two of the operations you are doing different things one is appending existing string and another you are setting a new string

To append string there should be a string object

```
self.consoleText = [self.consoleText stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:str]];
```

As per understanding self.consoleText ---> nil so it will not appending string.

so do something like

```
if(self.consoleText)
{
    self.consoleText = [self.consoleText stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:str]];

}else
{
self.consoleText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:str];
}
```

Comment: Works well after added initialization: `self.consoleText = @"";`

Comment: If you're debugging in the console, you can "p" instead of "po" and it will also do the job.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *original = @"Thinking";
const char *str = "...";
NSString *other = [NSString stringWithCString:str encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
original = [original stringByAppendingString:other];
NSLog(@"original: %@", original); // original: Thinking...
```

Comment: Sorry, just realized it and switched it over. I guess I need to look at the documentation more often.

Comment: You could also do `NSString *other = [original stringByAppendingFormat:@"%s", str];`